# SQL Caching on Django

Tags: mysql, django, caching

I have a friend and he's developing a prototype website off his laptop.  It's a cool site, very data driven and does some cool stuff on the fly.  Problem is, it takes like 10 seconds to load on his local machine.

Is there a way he can cache the results of the queries?  There are probably only a few thousand potential queries that need to be made and the resultant data won't change.

Google gave me nothing, so I turn to humans.  Any ideas?

Comment: I can understand his reluctance. That's a lot of data to cache! There are cca. ~200 countries in the world, so it's definitely sane to have that precomputed and stored somewhere. I'm guessing he's just struggling with coming up with a good cache design or figuring out an optimal invalidation interval. Caching sometimes involves a struggle of combating premature optimization when you don't have any clear indicators of the kind of the load the app will be getting and how often new data will get written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe [johnny-cache](http://packages.python.org/johnny-cache/)?

Also, please look at [this article](http://jeffelmore.org/2010/09/25/smarter-caching-of-django-querysets/), it covers Django QuerySet caching, and it’s really detailed.

Answer (score 4):

? django can cache queries : http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api